# Create point chart with points to be displayed as inner and outer circle,inside each other, with size analog to their value

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

Im trying to create a chart with points in which the `mpg` will be displayed as a grey dot and `qsec` as a green. The thing is that I want the 2 dots to be displayed like inner and outer circle. And of course their size should be analog to the value they display.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
    p <- mtcars%>%ggplot(aes(x=wt))+
      geom_point(aes(y=x,size=mpg*2),color="gray")+
      geom_point(aes(y=x,size=qsec),color="darkolivegreen")+
      scale_x_continuous(n.breaks=14)+
      theme(legend.position = 'none',
            axis.title.y = element_blank(),
            axis.text.y = element_blank())+
      labs(x="")
    p 
ggplotly(p)
```

Comment: What variable are you trying to plot on the y axis? You have `aes(y = x...` but there is no variable called `x` in `mtcars`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified a y axis variable, so there is nothing to plot. At the moment your code throws an error because there is no variable called `x` in `mtcars`.

If, for example, you want `hp` on the y axis, your code works as expected.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

p <- mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(wt)) +
      geom_point(aes(y = hp, size = mpg * 2), color = "gray") +
      geom_point(aes(y = hp, size = qsec), color = "darkolivegreen") +
      scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 14)+
      theme(legend.position = 'none',
            axis.title.y    = element_blank(),
            axis.text.y     = element_blank()) +
      labs(x = "")
 
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]